# Teaching question: Good textbook for basic online statistics course

Tags: references, teaching

I will teach an online course on Intro Stats at an Economics Department of a non-flagship public university in the US. I want to cover descriptive stats, basic probability (with common discrete and continuous distributions), hypothesis testing, and possibly Anova. Most practical exercises will probably be done in Excel (I know...).

Does anyone have a recommendation for a low-cost textbook that offers additional instructor resources geared towards an online course, and that comes with ready-made data sets for practice questions?

Comment: Did you lookup syllabi of similar courses in peer universities? That would be the place to start for me. You could totally scrape the syllabus from someone's course too and adapt it to your class

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have looked around. The main problem is price, as my university has a strict affordability policy on textbooks for online courses (<=US$60) and/or additional resources. Hard to square the circle of low price and a good test bank and data sets.

Comment: I like that your school sets the upper limit. School textbook business is getting out of hand lately. I truly see no reason why would anyone need 17th edition of stat 101 course, the thing's been the same for the past 50 years, any old textbook should be just fine

Comment: How about https://www.openintro.org/stat/ ? Free to download and comes with data sets, instructor resources. Book is also available to buy online and meets your price requirement too. Another possible option is to look at [link]openstax https://cnx.org/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'd open for something like this, but I've found this article that talks about [forecasting data based on ML concepts](https://www.uruit.com/blog/2018/02/16/soccer-and-machine-learning-tutorial/?utm_source=foros&utm_medium=textlink), it may be interesting for bringing a more modern overview of the subject. Hope it can be useful!